# Google Pagespeed keeps saying I need to optimize my images even though they have been compressed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexslider, pagespeed

I run my website through google pagespeed insight, and my desktop gets a 90 for a score. but my mobile is 65. it says my images need to be optimized with a red score, saying each image in my slider could be optimized for like 90-95% reduction. however I've gone through those images through a ton of different compressors, smushit, jpegcompressor, and all of them say the images cant be reduced anymore.......

I have a feeling its because I have the images in the slider be responsive so when I shrink the screen or view on mobile the slider is smaller. I think google is confused ... and I'm confused. How do I make my slider images optimized and responsive? Is this a resizing issue? and how should I fix it? I'm stumped.

Comment: If they are bigger then need be, you get penalized. I have images compressed to 25% but the dimensions are twice as big. This way they look good on normal and retina displays but remain the same filesize as what the image would be compressed with normal dimensions. I really don't care about that small issue on google's score, though mine doesn't drop to 65...

Comment: so should I resize the original images in, lets say, photoshop? cause I think I just do like max-width:100% height: auto type of thing in css

Comment: Your images are compresses appropriately for desktop where as for mobiles 1)you dont need that big resolution for starters. have smaller resolution pics and compress them for mobiles these might help -http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/03/one-solution-to-responsive-images/

Comment: It depends on your site structure, best is if it's done automatically. I do have a mobile detect serving way smaller images than they are on desktop browsers, might be why mine doesn't drop as low. Have a read at what @Sudheer posted. Somewhere along the lines you have to consider how to automate what you're doing, if you use a upload script, consider it resizing a second image automatically upon upload with a slightly different filesize, like .jpg becomes _small.jpg, mobile detect => get ext, rename _small.$ext... food for thought.